# Raphael JS, Path animation

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have a path:

```
var original_param = 'M '+p1.x+' '+p1.y+'L '+p2.x+' '+p2.y;
var path = paper.path(original_param);
```

I have defined another path attribute for animation:

```
var animation_param={M: p11.x+' '+p11.y, L: p22.x+' '+p22.y}
```

where `p1` and `p2` are points, I do not put their definitions here, since they return the proper values correctly here.

Then I animate the path with the parameters by:

```
path.animate(animation_param, 1000);
```

But I got error message

[image]

What is the reason of this error?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try use animation_param as string except object? 
I think it should work.